# How to automatically enable the below script for all users that are editing a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a script which tells me the date when someone made a change to a certain column but the problem is that is script is only running for me and not all users who are using that sheet.

The owner of the sheet is someone else - requesting them to enable the script from his end would be enough to run this for everyone or is there another way to get this done?

Any help would be appreciated. THank you!

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (s.getName() !== "Form Responses 11") return; // exit if not in "Data"
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if (r.getColumn() !== 18 ) return; // exit if not editing col D
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
  // make a stamp or remove the stamp based on current cell value
  if (r.getValue())
    nextCell.setValue(new Date())
  else nextCell.clear();
}
```

Comment: A simple `onEdit` trigger should execute when the spreadsheet is edited no matter which user does the edit. If these other users have edit access to the spreadsheet, they should have access to the script too. What makes you think the trigger is not executing?

Comment: I hope you realize that the onEdit trigger is not produce when the form makes a submission it only fire on user edits.

Comment: @Iamblichus - when I check the sheet a few mins later after my team edits it, the date doesn't auto-populate. I have to manually erase and enter details in the cell again for the timestamp to reflect.

Comment: @Cooper - yep, I'm aware of the same. I want the timestamp to reflect only when a comment is updated in column E after a form is submitted (columns A to C are reserved for the data submitted via the form)

Comment: After your team edits the sheet and the date does not autopopulate - did you have a look at the [execution logs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#new-editor) to see if the trigger has fired and if the function ran successfully?

Comment: Yep, I did, it failed to run multiple times but I couldn't understand why it failed to run. But I've figured out the issue. The moment I created another sheet and did an importrange of the form responses into another sheet, it worked perfectly fine without any issues. Thank you for your help everyone!